# Copy one text field value to another text field on button click using Android java

Tags: java, android

i am new to android development. please help!
I want to copy the value of one text field into another text field when i click the button using Android java.
i had searched a lot online but i find it in java script.Kindly help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity { protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);} public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); return true; } public void onClick(View v){ Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer is correct!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();} public void onClick_copy(View v) { TextView Message = null; if (Message.getText().equals("Hello World")) { Message.setText("Hello!!!");}else { Message.setText("Hello World");}}}

Comment: <EditText android:id="@+id/txt1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn1" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_marginTop="31dp" android:ems="10" > <requestFocus /> </EditText>

Comment: <Button android:id="@+id/btn1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginBottom="104dp" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" android:text="Copy" android:onClick="onClick" />

Answer (score 1):

Get the text from one `EditText`:

```
String enteredText = editText1.getText();
```

Set the retrieved text to your other `EditText`:

```
editText2.setText(enteredText);
```

set an `OnClickListener` to your `Button` and now do that whole in it:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    String enteredText = editText1.getText();
    editText2.setText(enteredText);
});
```

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true; }
public void onClick(View v){
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer is correct!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();}
 public void onClick_copy(View v) {
 TextView Message = null;
if (Message.getText().equals("Hello World")) {
 Message.setText("Hello!!!");}else {
 Message.setText("Hello World");}}}

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

Comment: Can you plz help me where i have to insert this code which u gave me. i tried but it was giving errors:(

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Copy" 
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />